# updating camera helper projection matrix (three.js)

Tags: camera, three.js, helper

I'm switching a camera between two exported dummies from 3dsmax by setting it to use their matrixWorld properties.

```
camera_foreground.matrixWorld = (dummy_shot1.matrixWorld);
camera_foreground.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

This works great but the camera_helper that I've created doesn't inherit the matrix changes.

It doesn't allow me to run updateProjectionMatrix() on the helper itself. I've tried parenting the helper to the original camera. I've also tried to set the helper.matrixWorld to the same dummy_shot1.matrixWorld. What would be the best way to get the helper to update along with the camera it's created for/from?

Comment: So both `camera_foreground` and `dummy_shot1` are `THREE.Camera` objects, I'm right?

Comment: What's the class of the `dummy_shot1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3dsmax cameras/camera animation aren't supported by the 3dsmax collada exporter. To get around this I was exporting dummies (from max to threejs) that had been parented to said cameras. I had worried that the dummies would come through without their animation (since the parents (3dsmax cameras) are ignored).

The dummies were coming through fine (I'd thought) since camera location/rotation worked fine when copying matrixes to three.js cameras. The problem arose when trying to get the helpers to do the same (apparent when viewing the scene via a debug camera).

It seems camera_helper objects in three.js don't play nicely with the matrix of these particular dummies (probably because in 3dsmax they are inherting from a parent). What's strange is that the cameras (as mentioned above) work fine.

To get around the issue I used a great maxscript (http://www.breidt.net/scripts/mb_collapse.mcr) to copy/bake all the parent keyframe data from the 3dsmax camera to it's dummy (no longer inheriting). The collada friendly dummy was then exported to three.js where both the camera and it's helper work great with.

Thanks Neeh for help and questions. It was rebuilding a test scene to upload that I noticed the new dummies (not parented to cameras) worked fine with helpers.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the frustum of a camera helper with [`THREE.CameraHelper.update()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/helpers/CameraHelper).

Given two cameras: `camera1` and `camera2`, you can switch the `CameraHelper` transformation from `camera1` to `camera2` like this :

```
cameraHelper.camera = camera2;
cameraHelper.matrix = camera2.matrixWorld;
cameraHelper.update();
```

**Note**

Another solution that seems more convenient for you, would be to create one `THREE.CameraHelper` for each camera and switch the currently displayed helper with :

```
camera1.helper.visible = false;
camera2.helper.visible = true;
```

In addition, [`THREE.Layers`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Layers) can also be used to control the currently displayed helper.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've tried `camera_foreground_helper.update()` but it seems to make no difference. I'm not switching cameras but moving the same camera between two dummies eg `camera_foreground.matrixWorld = (dummy_shot1.matrixWorld);`. I've tried also doing the same for the helper`camera_foreground_helper.maxtrix = (dummy_shot1.matrixWorld);` and then  `camera_foreground_helper.update();`

Comment: The only way I've got the cam _helper to offset with the foreground camera is by recreating it constantly (a terrible hack). FOV changes update in my debug view fine but when the foreground camera moves to a new dummy matrix the helper stays behind and only inherits FOV

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so I can see where's the problem?

Comment: So in the process of making my (first) fiddle, I replaced the dummies (that come in via dae/collada) with cube's made in three.js. This actually works as intended (I didn't even need to run update() on the helper since it worked just by explicitly setting the matrix). Not sure why the matrixWorld method doesn't work on the imported dummy but it works on the camera itself? Could it be that the dummies have keyframe rotation animation?

Comment: maybe because you have to `scene.add()` your dummy to the scene.
Can you link your fiddle please? :)

Comment: can you include collada files in a fiddle? Sorry I'm new to three.js/fiddles/coding :)

Comment: I think it works when loaded from [dl.dropboxusercontent.com](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/), otherwise just put your code and add your dummies manually so I can have a better idea of your code. BTW, what's the Three.js class of your `dummies`?

Comment: CameraHelper.update has no effect on my side :( ... only workaround I found is to remove the helper and add a new one, terrible three.js